# Keep inline CSS when printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a print.css file to format my page for printing. I've got the layout down great, but have an issue with some colors.

I have a table that has the cells formatted with a certain color background based on the value of the number in the cell. This is done via javascript that executes when the table is finished loading the values (using datatables.js).

Like this:

```
function colorIndex(data) {
$(".index_num").each(function() {
    var x = $(this).text();
    if (x <= 25) {
        $(this).css("color", "white")
        $(this).css("background-color", "#1d5792")
    } else if ((x > 25) && (x <= 50)) {
        $(this).css("color", "white")
        $(this).css("background-color", "#2e7fb5")
    } else if ((x > 50) && (x <= 80)) {
        $(this).css("color", "black")
        $(this).css("background-color", "#6db5d8")
    } else if ((x > 80) && (x <= 115)) {
        $(this).css("color", "black")
        $(this).css("background-color", "#cacaca")
    } else if ((x > 115) && (x <= 140)) {
        $(this).css("color", "black")
        $(this).css("background-color", "#fd9245")
    } else if ((x > 140) && (x <= 165)) {
        $(this).css("color", "white")
        $(this).css("background-color", "#e5560a")
    } else if (x > 165) {
        $(this).css("color", "white")
        $(this).css("background-color", "#7b3014")
    } else if (x == null) {
        $(this).css("color", "white")
        $(this).css("background-color", "#7b3014")
    }
});
}
```

This works great, the styles are all added inline and everyone is happy. However, when I go to print, the styles are ignored and the boxes all print without a background color. How can I change my code to ensure these do print with the right background color?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a media print?

Comment: Yes...all the other formatting I'm doing (like layout and hiding items) works fine. I guess the question is around ensuring that inline CSS is actually used a print media query.

Comment: Does [`-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust) fit your needs?  It should force the colours on an element with this property to appear in prints.  Put it on `body` to force all colours to print.

Comment: Are you sure it's not your browser?  Some browser don't print background colors and images unless you set it up to do so.

Comment: @JamesWilkins It's not printing any colors that are inline styles. For example, I have fonts that are supposed to be a different color using inline styles and they just print as black

Comment: @jonmrich any luck getting a solution figured out?

Answer (score 2):

One thought... instead of assigning inline style properties to the elements with JS, you may need to go about it in another way.  You could try applying the background color in the form of a class (that's defined in your print stylesheet), or even appending new style elements to the head.

Comment: This could be an interesting workaround if I can't find something more direct using what I have now.

Answer (score 2):

Printing background colors has to be [turned on](http://its.yale.edu/node/3666/lightbox2) in the print settings of the browser. Otherwise, no amount of background styling is going to make any difference.

Using the non-standard [`-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust) property might work in WebKit browsers like Chrome and Safari, but won't elsewhere. (There's a [proposal for standardization](https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/print-backgrounds), but it isn't there yet.)

If printing the background color is really important, and you can't control the settings of the user's browser, you might be able to hack something together with absolutely positioned colored images stretched to fill out the cells.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense and could be another workaround. I didn't know the part about background color in browser printing. Makes sense why it would be there though. What about other inline styles like my font colors?

Comment: It seems like some browsers prevent printing white text when not printing background colors, since it likely won't show up. How did you decide to tackle the issues with background colors?